# Statment running significantly slower than component parts and causes high CPU usage

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running the following statement in SQL Server Studio 2008:

```
Use Systems

select subdirectory 
from [Systems].[dbo].[ScanningArchiveFileSystem] f 
where f.FileFlag = 1 
and SubDirectory not in
(
    Select m.strSchemeCode + N'\' + f.FileRef AS P3_Skem 
    from  AdminWIP_DS.dbo.fnTblMembers(NULL) AS m 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN AdminWIP_DS.dbo.tblScannedItems f 
    ON m.intMemRef = f.intMemRef 
    AND m.intSystem = f.intSystem 
    where RIGHT(m.strSchemeCode + N'\' + f.FileRef,5) like '%.%'

    union

    select (m.skem COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  + '\' + f.strPath COLLATE latin1_General_CI_AS ) as filepath
    from AdminWIP_DS.dbo.tbl_Client_BAY_MemberFiles f 
    join p3Test.dbo.MEMBERS m 
    on m.MEMNO = f.intMemRef 
    and RIGHT(f.strPath,3) = 'pdf'
)
```

Each select statement runs with the following times:

```
select subdirectory 
from [Systems].[dbo].[ScanningArchiveFileSystem] f 
where f.FileFlag = 1
```

Rows 247769, Time 1 Secs

```
Select m.strSchemeCode + N'\' + f.FileRef AS P3_Skem 
from AdminWIP_DS.dbo.fnTblMembers(NULL) AS m 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN AdminWIP_DS.dbo.tblScannedItems f 
ON m.intMemRef = f.intMemRef 
AND m.intSystem = f.intSystem 
where RIGHT(m.strSchemeCode + N'\' + f.FileRef,5) like '%.%'
```

Rows 330442, Time 6 Secs

```
select (m.skem COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS  + '\' + f.strPath COLLATE latin1_General_CI_AS ) as filepath
from AdminWIP_DS.dbo.tbl_Client_BAY_MemberFiles f 
join p3Test.dbo.MEMBERS m 
on m.MEMNO = f.intMemRef 
and RIGHT(f.strPath,3) = 'pdf')
```

Rows 63133 0 Secs

and finally the Union as a whole runs as Rows 237660, Time 14 secs.

When I bring them all together for the "Not in" where clause CPU usage on the SQL Server goes up to 100% and so far I let it run for 20 mins and it didn't complete.

I'm not a SQL whiz so I was wondering if anyone could help with why the whole statement can take significantly longer.

Comment: Attaching the execution plan for the full query would likely help.

Comment: Also remember that 'UNION' outputs only distinct rows, so it more expensive than 'UNION ALL'

Comment: @ David Browne Isn't SQL Server smart enough to do NOT sort the rows within NOT IN?

Comment: @sepupic in order to make the result set unique / distinct by the UNION, it has to sort them.

Comment: @scsimon Did you look at execution plan for "...not in(....union)..." and "...not in(...union all)" ? Did you see any difference? Even if you ask server to first sort the result, it's smart enough to not to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your execution plan.

It can be that cardinality estimation for the last `Anti Semi Join` is wrong: 
you join 247.769 rows with 237.660 rows and there should be `Hash Join` but if it underestimated cardinality (AdminWIP_DS.dbo.fnTblMembers()) it used `NL` so you've got your 20 minutes.

Another thing to consider here is to eliminate `right join`:

You concatenate 2 strings and if one of them is `null` you'll get `nul`l as the result.

Comment: If you cannot see execution plan, you can check if it's your case this way: save your select from AdminWIP_DS.dbo.fnTblMembers(NULL) into #tmp, i.e. do select ...into #tmp, then add the rows from from AdminWIP_DS.dbo.tbl_Client_BAY_MemberFiles in the same table (insert into #tmp select from AdminWIP_DS.dbo.tbl_Client_BAY_MemberFiles) and then re-run your query against this #tmp table: ...where SubDirectory not in (select SubDirectory from #tmp), this way server will know the cardinality of #tmp and will choose the correct join type